# An unserer oder unsere Entwicklung

Tags: dative, standard-german, gender, accusative

Ich bin mir bei diesem Text nicht genau sicher, ob der Akkusativ oder Dativ genutzt werden sollte.

Der Text lautet:

> a) Ein Dank an alle Mitarbeiter für ihren Beitrag an **unserer** erfolgreichen Entwicklung.
> b) Ein Dank an alle Mitarbeiter für ihren Beitrag an **unsere** erfolgreichen Entwicklung.

Danke!

Answer (score 1):

Wie in Kommentaren zu [einer anderen Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71463/1487) diskutiert wurde, ist die Formulierung *»einen Beitrag an etwas leisten«* nicht im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum üblich, sondern nur im Süden (Österreich und Schweiz, Teile Süddeutschlands). Weiter im Norden scheint *»einen Beitrag **zu** etwas leisten«* üblicher zu sein, was für mich (Österreicher) aber etwas gespreizt und unsympathisch klingt, weswegen ich (wie die meisten meiner Landsleute) die Version mit *»an«* bevorzuge. Korrekt sind jedenfalls beide Versionen.

Während die Präposition *zu* ausschließlich mit dem Dativ verwendet werden kann, ist *an* eine Wechselpräposition, die mit Dativ und Akkusativ verwendet werden kann:

> 1. zu + Dativ: Die Spinne läuft zu der Wand.
> 2. an + Dativ: Die Spinne läuft an der Wand.
> 3. an + Akkusativ: Die Spinne läuft an die Wand.

1 und 3 bedeuten eine Bewegung, die auf ein Ziel gerichtet ist. (Die Spinne läuft auf dem Boden und versucht die Wand zu erreichen.) Der Satz Nr. 2 bedeutet, dass die Bewegung an einem Ort stattfindet (Sie nähert sich nicht der Wand, sondern sie ist die ganze Zeit dort.) Der Satz *»Die Spinne läuft zu die Wand.«* ist falsch.

Im vorliegenden Fall findet die Bewegung im übertragenen Sinn statt. Das sind die beiden Möglichkeiten:

1. Auf ein Ziel gerichtet (Akkusativ):
   Das würde bedeuten, dass der Beitrag außerhalb der Entwicklung stattfindet und das versucht wird, die Entwicklung zu erreichen.
2. An einem Ort (Dativ):
   Das bedeutet, dass der Beitrag ein Teil der Entwicklung ist, und dass der Beitrag innerhalb der Entwicklung stattfindet.

Die Deutung 1 macht nicht viel Sinn, denn die Mitarbeiter ernten ihren Dank nicht dafür, dass sie sich der Entwicklung angenähert haben (ohne an der Entwicklung teilgenommen zu haben), sondern dafür, dass sie etwas entwickelt haben. Ihr Beitrag war ein Teil der Entwicklung, daher scheidet die Variante mit dem Akkusativ aus. Richtig ist also der Dativ:

> Ein Dank an alle Mitarbeiter für ihren Beitrag an **unserer** erfolgreichen Entwicklung.

---

###### Nicht mehr Teil der eigentlichen Antwort:

Belege für »Beitrag **an** der Entwicklung«:

> Nach Meinung der Auftraggeber wäre der **Beitrag an der Entwicklung** der Fahrzeugausrüstung auf ETCS Level 2 - Niveau nur unwesentlich gewesen, was von Herrn B. bestätigt werden könne.
> <sub>[Bescheid des österreichischen Bundesvergabeamts](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/VergEntscheidung.wxe?Abfrage=Verg&Dokumentnummer=VERGT_20090408_N_0016_BVA_04_2009_15_00&IncludeSelf=True)</sub>

> Den größten **Beitrag an der Entwicklung** des ESH 6-10 leisteten die Hortkinder.
> <sub>[Danksagung in einer Masterarbeit an der Universität Wien](https://phaidra.univie.ac.at/open/o:1347538)</sub>

> Behinderte Menschen werden vom Versorgungsobjekt zu Subjekten, die an der Gesellschaft teilhaben und ihren **Beitrag an der Entwicklung** der Gesellschaft leisten.
> <sub>[Kritik an einer großen österreichischen Charity-Aktion, erschienen in VICE, einem Online Magazin mit Sitz in Berlin.](https://www.vice.com/de/article/jpm4bp/warum-behinderte-menschen-die-abschaffung-von-licht-ins-dunkel-fordern)</sub>

> Damit leisten wir international einen wichtigen **Beitrag an der Entwicklung** und Leistungsfähigkeit des Raumfahrtsektors.
> <sub>[Zitat des österreichischen Außenministers Schallenberg, wiedergegeben in den Salzburger Nachrichten.](https://www.sn.at/panorama/wissen/oesterreichs-seit-40-jahren-mitglied-bei-weltraumorganisation-esa-101906362)</sub>
> <sub>Dasselbe Zitat findet man auch auf einer [Seite des ORF.](https://science.orf.at/stories/3205697/)</sub>

> Der FSK ehrt Hubert Schmidt für seinen **Beitrag an der Entwicklung** neuer Anwendungsgebiete für in-situ-UF-Schaumkunststoffe
> <sub>[Artikel des Fachverbands Schaumkunststoffe und Polyurethane e.V. mit Sitz in Stuttgart](https://www.fsk-vsv.de/26-05-1983-der-fsk-ehrt-hubert-schmidt-fuer-seinen-beitrag-an-der-entwicklung-neuer-anwendungsgebiete-fuer-in-situ-uf-schaumkunststoffe/)</sub>

> Wir GRÜNEN werden auch in anderen personellen Besetzungen unseren **Beitrag an der Entwicklung** des Landes und unserer Städte leisten.
> <sub>[Blog eines österreichischen Lokalpolitikers](https://gerhardwannenmacher.at/2020/11/aehnlichkeiten/)</sub>

> Die unterschiedlichsten Profile, Studierende und Berufstätige im Alter von 17 bis 61 Jahren, haben sich an diesem Abenteuer beteiligt und ihren **Beitrag an der Entwicklung** der wegweisenden Projekte in den Bereichen sanfte Mobilität, Elektromobilität und nachhaltiger Konsum geleistet.
> <sub>[Artikel auf der Website des Schweizer Kantons Freiburg](https://www.fr.ch/de/rimu/afu/news/climathon-freiburg-am-24-und-25-september-2021-3-praemierte-projekte-3-innovative-ideen)</sub>

Comment: Bin mit allem einverstanden und sicher haben Sie es besser erklärt als ich.

Answer (score 0):

Beides klingt (wenigstens in meinen Ohren) nicht richtig, wenn auch die Variante a) - zumindest in Bezug auf den Kasus von "Entwicklung" - korrekt ist. Richtig ist tatsächlich *Dativ*.

Mein Sprachgefühl rät mir (ohne daß ich das allerdings begründen könnte) zur Verwendung von "zu" anstatt "an" in diesem Fall.

> Ein Dank an alle Mitarbeiter für ihren Beitrag **zu** unserer erfolgreichen Entwicklung.

Es gibt die Konstruktion "Beitrag an" durchaus, aber sie ist wenigstens in Deutschland (vermutlich mit Ausnahme von Süddeutschland, so genau wird es wohl schwer nachzuweisen sein) aber zumindest ungebräuchlich. Dort wird lediglich "Beitrag zu" verwendet. Es ist also die Frage, an wen sich Dein Text richtet. Die kannst Du am besten selbst beantworten und das ist für unsere Zwecke hier nicht relevant. Auch in Österreich (+Süddeutschland?) würde ich allerdings in diesem Fall "zu" vorziehen. Hingegen:

> Sein Beitrag **an** der Entwicklung war (groß, klein, ...).

In einem solchen Fall, wo "Beitrag" als Synonym für "Anteil" verwendet wird, würde ich "an" vorziehen. Wie schon gesagt, gut begründen kann ich das nicht. Vielleicht *trägt dazu bei*, daß die Wendung "daran beitragen" nicht existiert.

Was ich aber durchaus begründen kann, ist, warum der Text selbst in Variante a) nicht richtig ist:

> Ein Dank an alle Mitarbeiter für ihren Beitrag an unserer erfolgreichen Entwicklung.

In diesem Satz fehlt das Verb. Richtig wäre zB:

> Ein Dank **ergeht** an alle Mitarbeiter für ihren Beitrag an unserer erfolgreichen Entwicklung.

Allerdings würde ich eher direkte (An-)Rede verwenden:

> Ich danke (wir danken? die Firmenleitung dankt?) allen Mitarbeitern für Ihren Beitrag an/zu unserer erfolgreichen Entwicklung.

---

#### Nachtrag "Beitrag + Akkusativ"

Tatsächlich fällt mir nachträglich ein, daß die Wendung "Beitrag an + Akkusativ" durchaus möglich ist. zB., wenn jemand organisiert abergläubisch ist, dann

> ... zahlt er einen *Beitrag an die Religion* seiner Wahl.

Hier ist "die Religion" ein Akkusativobjekt.

Answer (score -2):

Beides ist möglich.

Dativ betont die Zusammenarbeit: Wir haben an unserer Entwicklung gearbeitet. Alternative: "... zu unserer erfolgreichen Entwicklung".

Akkusativ betont das Geben:

Jeder hat etwas gegeben, was unsere Entwicklung ermöglicht hat.

Allgemein ist der Akkusativ gebräuchlicher und kann immer benutzt werden; ein finanzieller Beitrag verlangt immer den Akkusativ (an unsere erfolgreiche Entwicklung).

Comment: Beide Alternativen sind insgesamt ungebräuchlich - "Beitrag" wird normalerweise mit "zu" verwendet (und "Anteil" mit "an").

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Erklärungen! Jedoch muss ich gestehen, ich verstehe die Erklärung von @Jeschu nicht genau. Ich nehme an etwas jemanden zu geben benötigt den Akkusativ, da es eine Richtung angibt? Den Punkt Zusammenarbeit versteh ich überhaupt nicht.

Comment: I disagree. "Beitrag an etwas" erfordert, dass 'etwas' im Dativ steht. Oder eben "Beitrag zu etwas" mit 'etwas' im Akkusativ. Der Kasus ergibt sich aus der Präposition. 'an' kann zwar mit Akkusativ stehen, aber nicht in dieser Bedeutung.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Ich widerspreche dir. *»Beitrag an etwas«* ist (zumindest in Österreich) nichts ungewöhnliches, und ich empfinde das als völlig korrekt: *»Jemand leistet einen Beitrag **an** etwas.«* Eine kurze Recherche ergab, dass das auch [in der Schweiz](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/beitrag-zu-an.2808369/) nicht ganz unüblich ist, aber eben in Deutschland (oder Teilen Deutschlands?) offenbar anders gesehen wird. Eine Google-Suche nach »"Beitrag an der Entwicklung"« liefert Treffer in österr. juristischen Texten, Masterarbeiten, Tageszeitungen und dem ORF.

Comment: @planetmaker Wenn schon, dann andersherum: zu ist immer mit Dativ, an kann mit Dativ oder Akkusativ stehen; Beitrag an Akkusativ ist sicher geläufiger (sagte ich bereits)

Comment: @Kilian auch in Deutschland werden Beiträge an Akk. gezahlt, nicht zu. In der Anfrage ist Beitrag zu Dat. korrekt.

Comment: @Jeschu: An den Kommentaren kannst Du ersehen, daß Deine Antwort - abgesehen von der vorhandenen oder nicht vorhandenen Richtigkeit - zumindest schlecht verständlich ist. Im Zweifelsfall ist es besser, etwas ausführlicher und genauer zu erklären - selbst auf die Gefahr hin, etwas zu wiederholen, was schon anderwo steht. Es ist auch möglich, das, was anderswo schon steht, per Link in der eigenen Antwort zu referenzieren.